# How to get matlab to randomly create a row array of (0,1,2) but only change numbers every 10th row

Tags: matlab

Is there any way you can create a row array where Matlab will randomly pick between 0,1, and 2 but only on every 10th row? I.e. it will look something like this:

0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
..... and keeps going so you end up with 100 rows?

Thanks!

Comment: An array with 100 rows and one column is a column array; not a row array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `randi` to generate the random numbers and `repelem` to get the blocks of 10

```
b = 10;  % block size
N = 100; % must be divisible by b
r = repelem( randi( [0,2], 1, N/b ), b );
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want something like this:

```
rndNumbers = randi([0,2],1,10);
rndNumbersRep = repmat(rndNumbers,10,1);
rndNumbersRep = rndNumbersRep(:);
```